# Writing Mysql and Php code in wordpress Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wordpress and i am writing php or mysql code in a post but finally when i hit publish it gives an Server Error : 500 , i also trying putting my code under [code] [/code] tags nothing happened but when i remove my codes and hit publish then it's working

Any idea guys
Waiting for help

Comment: Below is the error    Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator,and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: That error isn't helpful. We know what a Server Error 500 is; but it doesn't tell us anything. Look in your **error log**, as RiaD suggested. If it's Apache, and you're using some form of control panel, there's often a simple way of viewing the most recent errors. Else you may need to contact your host depending on your setup

Answer (score 0):

PHP code in the post? Can you use `page` instead of `post`? If yes, you could assing custom template for the page and execute code in it(I mean template). If no, try this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/